# Url encoding using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, urlencode, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-3.2

I am getting the response,and i want to send this value encode and next request,in UI i tried check encoded,looks still not working fine,is there any other way we can encode the response value.

In the screenshot in getrooms response i will get rate_id in decoded,so this value i have to encode and send in next request,please help
[image]

The response rate_id encoded value have to send in next call price check as a param.
[image]

Encode rate_id value.
"rate_id":"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"

Comment: it looks encoded already. please explain expected and current result

Comment: Sorry my bad,i want to decode my response

Comment: the decoded response value  i have to use in next price check call

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to come up with the comprehensive solution without seeing the full encoded data in **text form**, not as the image so consider extracting this `rate_id` from the response using [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor/)

It might be the case it's something easy like [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), in that case you can use i.e. [__base64Decode() function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#base64Decodesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-2-0-font-sup)

Otherwise you need to determine the algorithm and once done you will be able to decode the data using [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor)

Comment: Yes,i am using json extractor to extract the rate_id.
i copied encoded full rate_id in body
i tried base64 no luck

Comment: Thanks all,i have managed to encode using below.
${__javaScript(encodeURIComponent('${rate_id}'))}